# convert one nsdate to the time in a specific country

Tags: objective-c, ios, geolocation, nsdate

Assuming I have a point in time, represented by

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
```

for example:  **2012-11-07 13:44:55 +0000** (the local time of the device)

I also have an array of countries
each country has a name, and geo coordinates (log,lat)

for example: **England,51.5, -0.116667**

**Q:**
how would one calculate and convert the above date-time into the current equivalent time in a specific country?

*(As a side note, I rather have something local and not calling external API)*

Comment: An `NSDate` object does know about the time zone. You can only use the timezone when you are, for example, create a string form the date with `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: I agree with you, still how does one convert a time/date to the equivalent time in a specific country, for example the above date/time in england is 2012-11-07 17:44:55 in Moscow, Russia

Comment: You use the timezone property of [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but getting the [`NSTimeZone`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is hard if you only have coordinates.

Comment: I count not find "easy solution" in the text above ;)

Comment: That's because there is not "easy solution" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a list of time zones available by,

```
[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]
```

This would return something of this sort,

```
EST = "America/New_York";
GMT = GMT;
GST = "Asia/Dubai";
HKT = "Asia/Hong_Kong";
HST = "Pacific/Honolulu";
ICT = "Asia/Bangkok";
IRST = "Asia/Tehran";
IST = "Asia/Calcutta";
JST = "Asia/Tokyo";
KST = "Asia/Seoul";
MDT = "America/Denver";
MSD = "Europe/Moscow";
MSK = "Europe/Moscow";
```

Now use this time zone abbreviation key, say MSD for Moscow, to get the number of seconds that is offset in Moscow's time zone from the GMT.

```
NSInteger no_of_seconds = [[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"MSD"] secondsFromGMT];
```

The 'no_of_seconds' can now be added to the current date to get the date of the desired location, in this case Moscow,

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:no_of_seconds]
```